# What type of transformer is used in LLC converters? Is resonant or pulse the same thing?

Tags: transformer, resonant-converter

Often in the description of LLC converters, I hear the mention of a resonant transformer.

On [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer_types#:%7E:text=There%20are%20three%20primary%20types,is%20a%20wire%2Dwound%20transformer.), I found both resonant and pulse transformers.

In the photos of the LLC converters - the transformer is very similar to the pulse one. Only there, next to it, there is also a magnetizing inductor (Lm).

**Questions:**

1. What kind of transformer is used in LLC converters?
2. Are resonant transformer and pulse transformer the same?

If not, what are their main differences? (constructive / theoretical).

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A transformer used in an LLC converter *could* be a pulse transformer or, in fact, any transformer suitable for use at the operating frequency. It's not the transformer itself that is resonant; it's the use of it along with the capacitor shown as \$C_r\$ that produces a resonant frequency. Providing that the magnetization inductance (\$L_m\$) and leakage inductance (\$L_l\$) of the transformer's primary is well defined and fairly stable, then you get a defined resonant frequency. Using an extra inductance external to the transformer makes life easier of course but I'm not sure in your diagram if that's the case.

> *Only there, next to it, there is also a magnetizing inductor (Lm).*

All transformers have a primary magnetization inductance - it's basically the inductance of the primary winding (secondary ignored or not connected). It will usually dominate \$L_l\$.

Comment: thank you for the answer!

Before that I saw LC resonant converters, where before the transformer there were only Cr and Lr. Lm was not indicated at all.
Although it was probably as a primary winding.

In LLC, I noticed a clear highlighting of Lm. As I understand it, Lm is used to increase the stability of the transformer output over a wide range of loads.

LC and LLC scheme: https://imgur.com/a/qCJPaDP

Comment: I think you might need to dig a little deeper in order to distinguish what you want. Lm is always present in any transformer and some explanations may use it and some explanations may not because its magnitude may be much much bigger than Lr and can be ignored.